# How come Illuminator badge awarded to 23 users at the same time?

Tags: discussion, badges

[image]

[image]

How come all 23 users' awarded at the same time. !! Isn't it a strange thing? It may possible that there's variation in seconds but still its too strange. This means that all those user's started at the same time?

A link this badge is here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The badge was created on September 30.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator)

So it was immediately awarded to the 23 people who already qualified for it.

Comment: Is that something like, a badge named "SmartUser" created by SO team (today), the rule of this badge is that **the person having 10k reputation within first year of his joining into SO.**, if there are 23 users with this, would they get it immediately? Is that true?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment correctly. But the only way it's fair is to award the badge to everyone who qualifies for it. Even if they qualified for it before the badge was created.

Comment: Okey, not a big problem, but this may confirm that, if this is true, then whenever some badge will be create **this bunch of users** would get it immediately. Strange but true!

Comment: I just noticed this as well. Only thing that is concerning to me, now that it's 2015, is that it doesn't display the year. So I am assuming this happened in 2014, but in two years, who will know when it took place?